# assign in pandas pipeline

Tags: python, pandas

Say, I have the following DataFrame with raw input data, and want to process it using a chain of pandas functions ("*pipeline*"). In particular, I want to rename and drop columns and add an additional column based on another.

```
    Gene stable ID  Gene name   Gene type   miRBase accession   miRBase ID
0   ENSG00000274494 MIR6832     miRNA       MI0022677           hsa-mir-6832
1   ENSG00000283386 MIR4659B    miRNA       MI0017291           hsa-mir-4659b
2   ENSG00000221456 MIR1202     miRNA       MI0006334           hsa-mir-1202
3   ENSG00000199102 MIR302C     miRNA       MI0000773           hsa-mir-302c
```

At the moment I do the following (which works):

```
tmp_df = df.\
         drop("Gene type", axis=1).\
         rename(columns = {
            "Gene stable ID": "ENSG",
            "Gene name": "gene_name",
            "miRBase accession": "MI",
            "miRBase ID": "mirna_name"
         })

result = tmp_df.assign(species = tmp_df.mirna_name.str[:3])
```

result:

```
    ENSG            gene_name   MI          mirna_name      species
0   ENSG00000274494 MIR6832     MI0022677   hsa-mir-6832    hsa
1   ENSG00000283386 MIR4659B    MI0017291   hsa-mir-4659b   hsa
2   ENSG00000221456 MIR1202     MI0006334   hsa-mir-1202    hsa
3   ENSG00000199102 MIR302C     MI0000773   hsa-mir-302c    hsa
```

**Is it possible to put the `assign` command directly into the 'pipeline'?
 It feels cumbersome having to assign an additional temporary variable. I have no idea how I should reference the corresponding renamed column ('mirna_name') in that case.**

Comment: It looks like there are some good answers already, but note that in this case there is really no disadvantage to just doing the rename as a separate step.  In fact, for clarity I would generally prefer steps that merely drop and rename to be distinct from steps that actually do something (like creating a new variable derived from another variable with str[:3])

Comment: In this particular case, yes. However, [this blogpost](https://tomaugspurger.github.io/method-chaining.html) nicely illustrates how you will end up "[spending] time coming up with appropriate names for variables" and why pipes are nice.

Comment: Yes, that was my sole point: "in this particular case".  ;-)  I agree in many cases `pipe` or `assign` gives you a better way to do it and let's you avoid creating temporary variables that you will later delete.  In this case, I actually think it's worse (for readability) to combine everything on one line, but it's still a nice Q&A for how to do this sort of thing and I'm doing +1 for both the Q&A.

Comment: last comment...  the issue here is much less creating an "additional temporary variable" but rather creating an entire temporary **dataframe**.  The latter essentially doubles the memory usage whereas the former probably only has a trivial effect.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use pipe:

```
tmp_df = (
    df.drop("Gene type", axis=1)
    .rename(columns = {"Gene stable ID": "ENSG",
                       "Gene name": "gene_name",
                       "miRBase accession": "MI",
                       "miRBase ID": "mirna_name"}
            )
    .pipe(lambda x: x.assign(species = x.mirna_name.str[:3]))
)

tmp_df
Out[365]:
              ENSG gene_name         MI     mirna_name species
0  ENSG00000274494   MIR6832  MI0022677   hsa-mir-6832     hsa
1  ENSG00000283386  MIR4659B  MI0017291  hsa-mir-4659b     hsa
2  ENSG00000221456   MIR1202  MI0006334   hsa-mir-1202     hsa
3  ENSG00000199102   MIR302C  MI0000773   hsa-mir-302c     hsa
```

As @Tom pointed out, this can also be done without using pipe in this case:

```
(
    df.drop("Gene type", axis=1).
    .rename(columns = {"Gene stable ID": "ENSG",
                       "Gene name": "gene_name",
                       "miRBase accession": "MI",
                       "miRBase ID": "mirna_name"}
            )
    .assign(species = lambda x: x.mirna_name.str[:3])
)
```

Comment: The `.pipe` isn't needed here. You can put the lambda inside the assign like `.assign(species = lambda x: x.mirna_name.str[:3])`

Comment: @Allen, do you want to update your answer accordingly?

Comment: [`.assign()` has been around since 0.16/ 2015 in fact](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0160-enhancements)

Comment: What about if you want to do a groupby before the assign?

Answer (score 3):

```
result = df.drop("Gene type", axis=1).\
     rename(columns = {
        "Gene stable ID": "ENSG",
        "Gene name": "gene_name",
        "miRBase accession": "MI",
        "miRBase ID": "mirna_name"
     }).assign(species = df['miRBase ID'].str[:3])
```

You can reference the renamed column as df[column_name].

Comment: I wonder if this is correct. Inside `assign()`, the `df` still contains the previous column name. Following [pandas example](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), you can see that the following produces an error: `df.rename(columns={'temp_c': 'A'}).assign(temp_f=df['A'])`

Answer (score 1):

I found [pandas-ply](https://github.com/coursera/pandas-ply) which introduces a magic symbol `X` for that purpose:

```
import pandas as pd 
from pandas_ply import X, install_ply
install_ply(pd)

df\
     .drop("Gene type", axis=1)\
     .rename(columns = {
        "Gene stable ID": "ENSG",
        "Gene name": "gene_name",
        "miRBase accession": "MI",
        "miRBase ID": "mirna_name"
     })\
     .ply_select("*", species = X.mirna_name.str[:3])
```

would be nice to have this in native pandas, though.